# Barrel open event mineflayer

Tags: node.js, minecraft, mineflayer

I want to create a bot on mineflayer that would collect data about nearby players. One of these data is when the player has opened a container, such as a barrel or chest.

I've read the mineflayer [documentation](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/blob/master/docs/api.md), but it doesn't say anything about barrels. I only found the "chestLidMove" event, but it only works on chests.

Help me, how to figure out when someone has opened a barrel.

I would like to get something like this:

```js
bot.on("barrelOpened", (block, player) => {
   console.log(player);
})
```

Maybe this can be implemented somehow through the minecraft protocol?